# How is the ArrayList referenced in a getElementAt() method

Tags: java, arraylist, abstract

This is in java.

Alright so I am inheriting the abstract method `getElementAt(int)`. I want to **override this method** so that it finds an element at a specified index within an ArrayList. Since I am not actually passing an **ArrayList** into the method, I don't know how to reference it.

```
someArrayList.getElementAt(int n);
```

How does it access someArrayList within the method?

As for what I'm inheriting from

`public class ListEngine extends AbstractListModel`

and I am overriding the class

```
getElementAt(int n)
```

Comment: Is this Java? If you inherit from ArrayList, you call super.getElementAt(n); from your getElementAt() code.

Comment: share what you already have and what you tried.

Comment: If I call super.getElementAt(n) wouldn't I have simply referenced an  abstract class with no real information in it? Tried it anyways and it threw an error.

Comment: As to what I have tried? Well at the moment I haven't really done anything with it because I don't know how i'm supposed to call the ArrayList.

Comment: Are you inheriting from `javax.swing.AbstractListModel`? You need to explain your question better.

Comment: You are inheriting the abstract method from where? What is the class you are writing supposed to do? Perhaps you should tell us what the actual wording in your homework was.

Comment: Yeah, I import javax.swing.AbstractListModel and then my class extends it. Within my class I am trying to override the abstract method getElementAt(int n) so that I can return elements from my ArrayList. When trying to override this method I am at a loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well `AbstractListModel` does **not** provide an implementation on how the items are stored, etc.

What you thus need to do is use/implement a `List` object (or perhaps some kind of `Collection`) and then "redirect" calls to it:

**Example** (with `ArrayList`):

```
public class ListEngine<T> extends AbstractListModel {

    private final ArrayList<T> innerData = new ArrayList<T>();

    public ListEngine () {
    }

    @Override
    public T getElementAt(int index) {
        return innerData.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return innerData.size();
    }

}
```

Or you could use another `List` (like `LinkedList<T>`).

The above implementation is quite useless of course, since the initialized `innerData` is always empty. Furthermore **if something is modified to the `innerData`**, you need to call `fireContentsChanged` to notify the listereners (this is the responsibility of the inheriting class, doing not so can result in severe problems since some listeners may count on this).